# facebook page admin's response rate and response time through graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a facebook app and want to understand how can i retrieve the response rate and response time for a facebook page admin..
This is what i am looking for.....http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/some-facebook-page-admins-see-response-rate-response-time/620440

I tried to search it in the facebook developer site and google but most of the results are pointing to API response rate which I am not looking for...

Any help / reference is highly appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There´s no field for that in the API Reference, so most likely it´s not possible as of now: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page

Watch the changelog, maybe they´ll add the field in the future: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog